# MASM division for negative number

Tags: division, masm

I'm trying divide two numbers in assembly[Irvine-Intel x86 processor].
Here is my code:

```
    mov eax, 4
mov edx, 0
mov ebx, 2
div ebx
```

I get the correct answer for the division, but when i change the value to a negative number, it does not give me the correct answer.

```
    mov eax, -4
mov edx, 0
mov ebx, 2
div ebx
```

As I know, the "div" is unsigned divide. So how if I want to do division with negative number?

Answer (score 0):

You should use IDIV. 
IDIV instruction is a divide operation. IDIV is for signed numbers wheareas DIV is for unsigned numbers.

```
mov eax, -4
xor edx, edx ; mov edx, 0
mov ebx, 2
div ebx
```